# Proposal to move all poll questions to one big thread

Tags: discussion

I believe that "list of X" questions though as valuable as the OP intended to make it, still allows one line answers that require further research work by the community. To deal with this, I propose that one post in WebApps be modelled in a similar format to [TeX StackExchange's idea](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/tex-community-polls).

Please read their post to get an idea of what I mean.

- Using answers as poll titles
- Comments as answers

Comment: Interesting - will need to ponder this

Comment: I suggest trying this on ONE question to start.. not necessarily a fan of these questions in any form, so "bad versus slightly less bad" isn't a very meaningful distinction

Answer (score 2):

Since the comments of such can get rather hirsuite, let's think about promoting the highly upvoted comments into the post body and purging them from the suggested options.

Comments would need something above a dozen upvotes before getting made into the post since by that time the suggestion has "proven" itself as popular enough to be made more permanent than a comment lives to be.

It would keep the post and comments cleaner for all.

That is if we want to go down this route. If that means fewer of their ilk blathering on the site, let's rock it up.